# Query to retrieve user info who's shopping cart is larger then average value from all the users

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I need to write a query to get a list of a clients where the sum of all orders is larger than average value among all clients. I'm not allowed to use subqueries

```
select id_client, surname, id_order, data, count(*) as position_t, sum(shop_quantity) as quantity, 
sum(shop_quantity*d.price) as summa_order, (select avg(shop_quantity*d.price) from shopping_cart join product d on id_product = fk_product) as average
from client a
join `order` b on id_client = fk_client
join shopping_cart c on id_order = fk_order
join product d on id_product = fk_product 
join catalog e on id_catalog = fk_catalog
group by id_order
having summa_order > average
order by summa_order desc;
```

It should be something like this, but without subquery. How to write it?
Ouput is here:
[image]

Note: other aggregate functions should also work (sum, count)

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregation functions :

```
select 
    id_client
    , surname
    , id_order
    , data
    , count(*) as position_t
    , sum(shop_quantity) as quantity
    , SUM(shop_quantity*d.price) as summa_order
    , AVG(shop_quantity*d.price) OVER ( PARTITION BY shopping_cart.id_product) AS      average
from client a
join `order` b 
    on id_client = fk_client
join shopping_cart c 
    on id_order = fk_order
join product d 
    on id_product = fk_product 
join catalog e 
    on id_catalog = fk_catalog
group by id_order
having summa_order > average
order by summa_order desc;
```

I didn't change group by but you need all non-aggregate columns from select in your group by statements